# How to apply .sort() with a key=lambda function to every row of a dataframe on a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column containing a list of dates:

```
data = [
    [
        1,
        [
            "2017-12-06",
            "2017-12-05",
            "2017-12-06",
            "2018-01-03",
            "2018-01-04",
            "2017-11-24",
        ],
    ],
    [
        2,
        [
            "2019-03-10",
            "2018-12-03",
            "2018-12-04",
            "2018-11-08",
            "2018-11-30",
            "2019-03-22",
            "2018-11-24",
            "2019-03-06",
            "2017-11-16",
        ],
    ],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "dates"])
df

id  dates
1   [2017-12-06, 2017-12-05, 2017-12-06, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04, 2017-11-24]
2   [2019-03-10, 2018-12-03, 2018-12-04, 2018-11-08, 2018-11-30, 2019-03-22, 2018-11-24, 2019-03-06, 2017-11-16]
```

```
print(df.dtypes)
id        int64
dates    object
dtype: object
```

I would like to sort the date containing column (`dates`). I have tried a number of methods with no success (including `.apply(list.sort) in place`). The only method that I've found that works is using `.sort(key = ....)` like below:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    "2019-03-10",
    "2018-12-03",
    "2018-12-04",
    "2018-11-08",
    "2018-11-30",
    "2019-03-22",
    "2018-11-24",
    "2019-03-06",
    "2017-11-16",
]

dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

but I can only get it to work on a list and I want to apply this to that entire column in the dataframe `df`. Can anyone advise the best way to do this? Or perhaps there is an even better way to sort this column?

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is that you want the list in every row to be sorted (not the column itself).

The code below applies a certain function (something like `my_sort()`) to each row of column "dates":

```
df['dates'].apply(my_sort)
```

You just need to implement `my_sort` to be applied to the list in each row. Something like:

```
def my_sort(dates):
    dates.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
    return dates
```

`list.sort()` sorts the list and returns `None` so you need to return the list itself after calling `sort`.

**Edit**:

According to the comment from [@jch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3968761/jch), it's a better practice to copy the list first and then call `sort` method. This way, any unexpected behavior or error produced by `sort` method (if any happens) won't affect the original list (in your datafram). To achieve that, you can change `my_sort` to something like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def my_sort(dates):
    dates_copy = deepcopy(dates)
    dates_copy.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
    return dates_copy
```

You can learn more about `copy` and `deepcopy` of objects [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Comment: `List.sort` changes the passed object.  Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported.

Comment: @jch Thanks, that's a good point. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .apply() to apply a given function (in this case 'sort') to every row of a dataframe column.

This should work:

```
df['dates'].apply(lambda row: row.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")))

print(df)
```

returns:

```
   id                                              dates
0   1  ['2017-11-24', '2017-12-05', '2017-12-06', '2017-12-06', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04']
1   2  ['2017-11-16', '2018-11-08', '2018-11-24', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04', '2019-03-06', '2019-03-10', '2019-03-22']
```

---

Note that in this case the code `df['data'] = df['data'].apply(...)` will NOT work because the *sort* function has a default *inplace=True* parameter: it directly modifies the dataframe and doesn't create a new one.
To apply other functions you might have to use the `df = df.apply(etc)`formulation.

Comment: Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported.

Comment: Should we work on a copy of the df ?

Comment: You could do a deep copy in the apply function before you do the sort. See: delftstack.com/howto/python/deep-copy-list-in-python.  If you made a copy of the df first then you are still going against best practices.